# Integrating salesforce REST API with a 3rd party application

Tags: salesforce

i am looking into salesforce integration with my application using the REST API. Since there are limits on API calls and bandwidth, i need to procure more API calls. i will be going ahead with the ISVforce program.

Salesforce specifies that it will charge 15% of net revenue in case of a paid application. If i have 100 users on my application and only say 20 of these use Salesforce (Since we also integrate GMail, dropbox, Yahoo etc), will Salesforce charge me for 100 or 20?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a place to answer this type of question.Better, raise a case with salesforce.